# How to subdivide a classification problem

Tags: classification

I have a problem with a number of inputs and one binary output, which I have tried to train several classifiers to solve. Unfortunately, none of the classifiers (MLP, SVM, bagging) have achieved the required level of accuracy.

I am thinking of subdividing the problem by splitting the dataset into two, and using a different classifier on each half, or the same classifier but with different parameters (or the same parameters, but it will be learning a different problem).

One approach is to choose the attribute which has the highest correlation with the output, and split the data so that the lowest values are in one set, and the highest in another.  I fond that one set gave very good accuracy, whereas the other had a lower accuracy than the combined data set.

Is there an alternative approach to subdividing the problem that anyone can suggest?

Comment: The purpose of bagging and random forests and most other approaches is so that you don't need to divide the data again to run the algorithms.  And you did not explain why classification is of special interest as opposed to predicting risk.  What is the ultimate problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Frank the classifier will bypass an existing algorithm which is computationally expensive.  It is an engineering problem (I can't give any more details).  I am getting accuracies which are in the 90s but they want a minimum of 98%.

Comment: I've often wondered if using a tree with some of it's variables coming from other ML techniques (outputs of an svm, logistic regression etc) might not work in such a situation.

Comment: You still did not explain why you need arbitrary classifications as opposed to predicting probabilities of class membership.

Comment: @FrankHarrell because the engineering algorithm which this bypasses has a Boolean output

Comment: That doesn't explain why a Boolean output is desirable or why you are not interesting in knowing that some items are difficult to classify (i.e., have intermediate predicted risk).

Comment: Because the user expects a Boolean output in this case.  It wouldn't mean anything to them to have risk factors.

Comment: So the user demands a forced choice and is not interested in close calls or unclassifiable observations and does not have a utility function.  That's strange.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, the software currently runs an algorithm in a loop many times.  The inner part of the loop is being bypassed by a neural network.  When the network gives the desired output, it is then double-checked with the existing algorithm, and if the results tally then the loop terminates.  The advantage of this is that these expensive algorithms are only run once (if the network is accurate) instead of many times (since often only 1% of loop iterations give the desired output).  These algorithms also give the user some non-binary feedback of the sort of nature you describe.

Comment: But if the result is an all-or-nothing classification you have not addressed the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you just have to experiment by picking an attribute, splitting the data and then testing the results.  If there is no real improvement, pick another attribute.

Like many things to do with neural networks, there probably isn't a set formula for it as using the correlation is just a heuristic.

In my example, I had 29 attributes.  I split the data into two based on attribute which wasn't highly correlated to the output at all. The overall accuracy of the neural network improved from 88.3% to 97.7%.

Comment: The rationale for that strategy is unclear, and data splitting greatly reduces power unless the sample size is enormous.

Comment: What I didn't say @FrankHarrell is that I have an unlimited amount of training data. If you split the search space into two, then each neural network has a smaller domain, would this not tend to make it more accurate?  That was my rationale.

Comment: The reverse is true.  You need all the sample size you can get to fit models that are not pre-specified.

Comment: The sample size is not limited.  By dividing the problem into two you are making the problem smaller.